# What's the best way to store date information in SQLite for later sorting?

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

So I'd like to store database entries in an Android SQLite db with a time component and then be able to later select entries between certain months or days with a calendar.  What is the best way to do this? I thought about putting the date in the database in a year, month and day column so I use SQL commands to find a date range, but I'd like to do this the right way the first time.  How would I later pull out data between two random dates?  Thanks.

Mark

Comment: Store milliseconds.

Comment: Store TimeStrings. And use Google, before asking this kind of questions.

Comment: So if I used miliseconds how would I pull up results from a db between two dates?  And what function would I use to get the current time into that format?  Do the two answers above use the same method or different methods?

PS. I did use Google and there seem to be a hundred different answers and many are very old that's why I posted.

Comment: `... many are very old ...` but **still valid**.